# Traefik v2 dashboard returning "404 Not Found" on local k8s cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, traefik-ingress

Getting a 404 Not Found Error when trying to access the traefik dashboard on local k8s cluster. Does anyone have a solution to resolve this problem?

For further information please visit: [My Traefik Community Issue](https://community.traefik.io/t/404-not-found-on-traefik-dashboard-via-http-on-local-kubernetes-cluster/12487?u=bigd)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Issue resolved, for futher information check out the link below.

https://community.traefik.io/t/404-not-found-on-traefik-dashboard-via-http-on-local-kubernetes-cluster/12487/2?u=bigd